# Intercept route and modify it before ui-router responds in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using HTML5 pushstate on a mobile AngularJS website. When someone hits the desktop version, they get redirected to the mobile site. Sometimes the URL has a hash that the desktop site uses. The extra  `#` is causing me digest loop problems.

I want to modify the route string before UI router even has a chance to act on it. Given:

`http://www2.health.com.au/product/basic/#?blah` I only want UI router to read the path `/product/basic/`.

I've tried adding a rule to the route provider [(docs)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_rule) that checks for `'#?'` and splits the string - but this seems to have no effect:

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location){
  var path = $location.url();
  debugger;
  if(path[path.length - 1].indexOf('#?')){
    var splitpath = path.split('#?');
    $location.replace().path(splitpath[0]);
    return splitpath[0];
  }
});
```

And the route ends up like this: `http://www2.health.com.au/product/basic/#%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252.......`

With the error `10 $digest() iterations reached`

I was under the impression that rules intercept the route, change it if possible and then pass the fixed route for ui-router to handle. Can anybody shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

I am not particularly happy with this solution, but I ended up doing a manual bootstrap WITH A FREAKIN SETTIMEOUT!!! without it, `angular.bootstrap()` races the `window.location = ...` and wins unbelievably.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
  var loc = window.location.href,
    index = loc.indexOf('#?');

    if(index > 0){
      alert('needsfix');
      window.location = loc.substring(0, index);
      setTimeout(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['health3App']);
      }, 500);

    } else {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['health3App']);
    }

})
```